# Is an Azure Durable Entity singleton desirable or even possible?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm using an Azure durable orchestrated function paired with a durable entity. The entity's purpose is to dispense data back to the orchestrated function that the orchestrated function uses in a workflow. The entity has encapsulated logic to locate the appropriate data to dispense based on the data's state. Based on this requirement, the entity can be a singleton; in other words, it can always have the same entity key.

Everything works fine until the orchestrated function is restarted. When it invokes the durable entity's get method after the restart, the orchestrated function goes into the waiting state indefinitely. The code snippet is below.

```
        public static async Task RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger logger)
        {
            try
            {
                var sourceEntity = new EntityId(nameof(UploadDispenser), "UploadDispenserInstance");
                var dispenser = context.CreateEntityProxy<IUploadDispenser>(sourceEntity);
                var data = await dispenser.GetData();
                // Do something with the data.
                // If function was restarted, it goes into waiting state indefinitely.
                var next = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddMinutes(1);
                await context.CreateTimer(next, CancellationToken.None);
                context.ContinueAsNew(null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError($"Error in RunOrchestrator: {ex}");
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Notice that `sourceEntity` always has the same entityKey.

Can an entity key have a static value across orchestration runs? Why does the entity invocation hang? The only way I know to fix the issue is to reset the durable state, which is not a good solution.

I have tried terminating and restarting the instance, purging the history, and suspending and resuming the orchestration function, but none of these approaches seem to work.

Comment: Which line is it waiting on? `var data = await dispenser.GetData();` or `await context.CreateTimer(...)` ?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Azure Durable Functions, [but according to the documentation for `CreateTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.durabletask.idurableorchestrationcontext.createtimer?view=azure-dotnet), you need to pass in a real `CancellationToken`, and not `CancellationToken.None` in order for all Durable Timers to be cancelled which must happen before the orchestrator function completes.

Comment: should be a unique identifier that is specific to the particular instance of the orchestration, and should not be a static value that is reused across multiple instances. This is because each instance of the orchestration has its own state, and reusing the same ID could result in conflicts or unexpected behavior.

Comment: use a specific value ID, you can pass it as the second argument to the [StartNewAsync](https://i.imgur.com/VFWfXur.png) method to [constant id](https://i.imgur.com/Axyfo5E.png)

Comment: @Dai it is waiting on `var data = await dispenser.GetData()`

Comment: Dai - my understanding is you only need to pass in a cancellation token to CreateTimer if for some reason you need to cancel the timer before it expires. For example, you are executing an external task and you want the orchestration to do something if the external task takes longer than x seconds. If the external task is completed before x seconds, then you would cancel the timer using the cancellation token.

Answer (score 0):

Using a different entity key for each orchestration instance fixed the issue. I'm passing a GUID into the `StartNewAsync` method and using that as the entity key.